# Eclipse: TODO's not in source files

Tags: eclipse, task, todo

Is it possible to view TODO's in non-source files in the task view?

For example I have a README in my project where I had described some problems and have marked them with TODO. I hoped they will be visible in the task view, but they are not.

Any way to define additonal files to search for tasks?

Answer (score 0):

In the text editor right click on the marker bar (the vertical space just to the left of the text). Select 'Add Task..'. Make sure the Description text contains TODO click OK. The marker should then be shown in the default Tasks view.

The [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-2d2.htm) has more details.